# How can I fetch network logs at run time on Native App?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, appium, wdio, browserstack-app-automate

My requirement is to fetch network logs at runtime when my scenario is running via automation on native app.

I am using wdio automation framework ( JavaScript ) + cucumber framework and using appium library for native app automation. I am using browser stack for executions.

I am able to fetch network logs for web execution but not able to achieve the same for native app execution. Has anyone achieved this in their framework?